# PDF vs. DOC print processing

Tags: pdf, printing, pdf-generation, doc

I have a process that sends to printer a large amount of .doc files (with 50-200 pages each). Now, I want to change .doc format of documents to pdf because it's more convenient (for it's design possibilities and flexibility).

But (and it's probably a well known fact) - PDF documents are processed a much longer time by printers than .doc format.

Can I increase the speed of pdf processing somehow ?

Or may be you could suggest any other document format ?

Comment: What sort of printers? I would have thought that PostScript®-capable printers would be more than suitable for PDF documents.

Comment: Is it really well-known that pdf is slower?  Why would that be?

Comment: @Neil, I was talking about the xerox printers for typography, but any usual office printer does the same. The main problem is - I can't make them buy another printers, I have to use ones they own.

Comment: @chrisfarmer, I don't know why - that's why I posted this question actually, it might be I'm missing something obvious. Anyone I know, who tried to print the same document in .doc and .pdf - says the same - that .pdf is much slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention .DOC I assume these are Windows users, in which case you could consider the [XPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification) format.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the XPS format, but I'll certainly consider it. Thank you Neil.

Answer (score 0):

.doc files are not actually processed by the printer.  They are converted by a driver to a language the printer supports such as Postscript or PCL.  If you are finding that Word files seem to print faster it is most likely due to the print driver.  If you find that PDF is slower I assume you are running a PCL driver.  A PS driver will, in most cases, be set to Postscript passthrough which will allow the PDF to process very fast.  And, in some cases, the PDF is actually supported as a native language and as such you can just LPR or send the PDF to the printer over port 9100 and it will print, fast (in most cases).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Douglas Anderson. Unfortunately we can't modify drivers or the way printer is getting data - all is done by on-board computer, and cannot be changed.